# Flask cached files, no new changes applied (still loads old .css and .js files)

Tags: caching, web, flask, debian

I have simple flask application running on flask development server on Debian9. Everything worked fine until today. Now, when I change any of the files in **static** directory, the browser loads the old file and no change is displayed. 2 browsers tried: Chrome and IE.

I've tried this:

1. Clear all browser cache, refresh page = no effect
2. Install 2 brand new browsers (Vivaldi and Opera) = On the first time the URL was entered, old .css files were loaded
3. When I rename the .css file and accordingly modify the html, the changes are applied and everything looks fine until I make another change, then I have to rename it again.

I run flask app with **flask run --host='0.0.0.0' --port='80'**

I found many similar posts, everytime they were solved by clearing browser cache, or adding @app.after_request decorator, but it did'nt help in this case. I don't think this is browser cache related. Thank you for any advices.

Comment: What happens if you restart apache? Do your files load?

Comment: Thanks CodeLikeBeaker. There is no apache, flask has it's own development server.

Comment: I had this problem as well in the past, have you tried not using the dev/debug server?

Comment: thanks Clint, I did'nt deployed my app to apache or something else. I think that the problem is solved out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many desperate hours of trying, I find out, that this behaviour is caused by multiple ssh sessions opened to the server. I had 2 connections via putty, one for starting and stopping server, second for files modifications. I've tested it with opening and closing the second putty connection and it's definitely the cause of the problem. I don't know if this is related only to flask (I'm no linux expert), but maybe it'll help someone.